# Shuffling an Array with another array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to mix an array order, without losing any of it's content. It's a deck of cards that I want to mix it up.

I have multiple files which I am using to communicate, here is where the problem lies:

```
class Deck{

    private:
         PlayingCard deck[52];

    public:
         Deck();

         void shuffle();

         double draw(); 

         void printDeck();
};
```

So then I create an instance of the deck and I'm able to print out the whole deck properly, and I just want to mix it up:

```
void Deck::shuffle(){
    int randNum;
    string tmp;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        randNum = rand()%52;
        deck[i] = deck[randNum];
    }   
}
```

So I know that I am assigning a random number and nothing prevents it from getting a the same random number twice. I am not sure if there is another way to call a random number without getting it twice or if there is another method I should call. Because how I have it mixes the cards up but it cant print the same card twice which should not be possible.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`std::suffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)? But if you insist on DIY, a hint: don't assign, swap.

Comment: The examples we were given use something similar to that? so instead of equal what should I do? In his example, he does exactly what I have and it doesn't work. @IgorTandetnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    deck[i] = deck[randNum];
```

This will give incorrect behavior because you are making a second copy of deck[randNum] (as long as randNum != i)

If you want to swap two numbers you could do

```
PlayingCard tmp = deck[i];
deck[i] = deck[randNum];
deck[randNum] = tmp;
```

Or

```
std::swap(deck[i], deck[randNum);
```

Or as Igor Tandetnik pointed out, you could use std::shuffle instead of the whole loop.

Comment: Thank you simple enough. Knew I was close!